# can not find logs of resque worker as a systemd service

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

im hosting/supporting a Ruby on Rails application without any Ruby background myself. The application itself is mostly used in germany if i am not mistaking. But my Problem hat nothing really to do with the application but rather with the resque worker which is used.

I configured the resque worker as a systemd service as seen here:

```
[Unit]
Description=resque-worker for pageflow

[Service]
User=pageflow
WorkingDirectory=/home/pageflow/pageflow_daad
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/bundle exec /usr/local/bin/rake resque:work > 
/home/pageflow/pageflow_daad/log/resquework.log &
#ExecStart=/home/pageflow/.rbenv/shims/rake resque:work &
Environment=QUEUE=*
Environment=RAILS_ENV=production

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

This worker handles image/video uploads without problems. Now i added a new application feature which crawls specific pages. This process is handled by the worker as well. In this case i end up with an error which i cant find in any logs. To be specific i cant find any logs from the worker or sheduler at all.

I looked in these locations by now:

- Applicationroot/log/production.log
- Applicationroot/log/jobs/production (which is not used anymore as told by the app developer)
- /var/log/nginx/error.log
- journalctl -u resque-worker.service

This is the output of `systemctl status resque-worker.service`

```
esque-worker.service - resque-worker for pageflow
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/resque-worker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2021-03-11 13:46:52 CET; 3 days ago
 Main PID: 30864 (bundle)
    Tasks: 5
   Memory: 186.0M
      CPU: 2min 10.308s
   CGroup: /system.slice/resque-worker.service
           └─30864 resque-1.27.4: Waiting for default,mailer,mailers,resizing,scraping,slow

Mar 11 13:46:52 ostheim-stg bundle[30864]: Gem::Specification#rubyforge_project= called from /home/pageflow/pageflow_daad/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/specifications/zencoder-2.5.1.gemspec:15.
Mar 11 13:46:52 ostheim-stg bundle[30864]: NOTE: Gem::Specification#rubyforge_project= is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2019-12-01.
Mar 11 13:46:52 ostheim-stg bundle[30864]: Gem::Specification#rubyforge_project= called from /home/pageflow/pageflow_daad/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/specifications/vegas-0.1.11.gemspec:17.
Mar 11 13:46:52 ostheim-stg bundle[30864]: NOTE: Gem::Specification#rubyforge_project= is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2019-12-01.
Mar 11 13:46:52 ostheim-stg bundle[30864]: Gem::Specification#rubyforge_project= called from /home/pageflow/pageflow_daad/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/specifications/rufus-scheduler-2.0.24.gemspec:16.
Mar 11 13:46:56 ostheim-stg bundle[30864]: DEPRECATION WARNING: Sprockets method `register_engine` is deprecated.
Mar 11 13:46:56 ostheim-stg bundle[30864]: Please register a mime type using `register_mime_type` then
Mar 11 13:46:56 ostheim-stg bundle[30864]: use `register_compressor` or `register_transformer`.
Mar 11 13:46:56 ostheim-stg bundle[30864]: https://github.com/rails/sprockets/blob/master/guides/extending_sprockets.md#supporting-all-versions-of-sprockets-in-processors
Mar 11 13:46:56 ostheim-stg bundle[30864]:  (called from block in <class:Railtie> at /home/pageflow/pageflow_daad/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/react-rails-1.8.0/lib/react/rails/railtie.rb:110)
```

Can anyone give me a hint where to further look for?
A also changed the applications log-level to :info to be sure to not miss any log.

Im using Rails 5.2.0 and Ruby 2.3.1p112

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to SO! How about asking `systemctl` to output more/piping it to a file? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/225401/how-to-see-full-log-from-systemctl-status-service

Answer (score 0):

After hours of research for some reason i now found the logs in the `Approot/logs/production.log` so the default Rails log location. I really dont know why i missed that beforehand. Maybe because i changed the line of the log level configuration....

So for future reference: even if the the resque worker is handled by systemd the logs still can be found in the application logging as configured in the environments.